# jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave function for an ajax called div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have called 4 div using ajax in div having class=displaycat. I wote a mouseenter and mouseleave jquery function for these div but it didn't work. Code is below. If is code these div in the page with out ajax call it works but not with jquery

```
<div id="cat">
   <h1>CATEGORIES</h1>
   <div class="displaycat" align="center">

   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"function/mpslidercm.php",
                data: ({action : "catmenu",
                         w : $('.displaycat').width()}),
                success: function(data){
                    $('.displaycat').html(data);
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('div#catdiv').each(function(){$('div', this).hide();});
                }
    });

    $('div#catdiv').mouseenter(function(){var submenu = 0;var text = $('img', this).attr('data-description');if (text === 'clothes'){submenu = '<p>CLOTHES</p><ul><li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li><li><a href="#">Pants</a></li><li><a href="#">Scarfs</a></li><li><a href="#">trousers</a></li></ul>';}else if (text === 'shoes'){submenu = '<p>SHOES</p><ul><li><a href="#">Party</a></li><li><a href="#">Fancy</a></li><li><a href="#">High Heals</a></li><li><a href="#">Sandels</a></li></ul>';} else if (text === 'bags'){submenu = '<p>BAGS</p><ul><li><a href="#">Gucci</a></li><li><a href="#">LV</a></li><li><a href="#">Chines</a></li><li><a href="#">Copy</a></li></ul>';} else if (text === 'access'){submenu = '<p>Accessories</p><ul><li><a href="#">Jewlery</a></li><li><a href="#">Bangels</a></li><li><a href="#">Braclets</a></li></ul>';}$(this).css('color', '#FFF');$(this).css('background-color', '#D63232');$('img', this).hide();$(this).height(200);$(this).width(320);$('div', this).text('');$('div', this).html(submenu);$('div', this).show();});

    $('div#catdiv').mouseleave(function(){$(this).css('padding', '0px');$(this).css('color', '');$(this).css('background-color', '');$(this).height(200);$(this).width(320);$('div', this).hide();$('img', this).show();});
});
</script>
```

Here is my ajax call php file

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $w= $_POST['w'];
    if ($action == 'catmenu')
    {
        $divsize = $w%2;
        if ($divsize == 0)
        {
            $w -= 10;
            $divsize = $w/4;
        } else {
            $w -= 9;
            $divsize = ($w-1)/4;
        }
        echo'<div id="catdiv"><img src="imgresize.php?src=resources/img/model2.png&w='.$divsize.'&h=200" data-description="clothes" /><div>Test</div></div>
        <div id="catdiv"><img src="imgresize.php?src=resources/img/shoes.jpg&w='.$divsize.'&h=200" data-description="shoes" /><div>Test1</div></div>
        <div id="catdiv"><img src="imgresize.php?src=resources/img/bag.jpg&w='.$divsize.'&h=200" data-description="bags"/><div>Test2</div></div>
        <div id="catdiv"><img src="imgresize.php?src=resources/img/acces.jpg&w='.$divsize.'&h=200" data-description="access"/><div>Test3</div></div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: i can't understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: Please look at the code now

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't create multiple divs with the same ID - it's not legal HTML.  Use a class instead (e.g. `.classdiv`)
2. Use `$('.displaycat').on('mouseenter', '.catdiv', ...)` to register a *delegated* event handler, which will work on dynamically added elements
3. Your `complete` handler can be replaced with: `$('.catdiv div').hide()`